# Is there a way to import pkgs as part of `cue eval -e`

Tags: cuelang

I'm trying to run `cue eval myfile.json -e` and the expression includes `regexp.FindSubmatch`. This works fine if I do the add the expression to a cue file with the proper imports at the top, but I'm testing to see if I can bypass generating a cue file and basically use cue in place of jq.

Is there a way with the cue cli to inject the import statements as flags or in the expression string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, this works out-of-the-box for me:

```
$ cat /tmp/a.json | jq
{
  "a": "foobar"
}

$ cue eval /tmp/a.json -e 'regexp.FindSubmatch(".o.", a)'
["foo"]

$ cue version
cue version v0.4.3 darwin/amd64
```

Did you mean a different use case?

Comment: No, I got an error `expected operand, found '.'`. But if I add triple quotes around the regex pattern it does work.